# calling method with NSDictionary (userInfo)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, nstimer

I've got a timer

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:x target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:y, @"y", z, @"z", nil] repeats:YES];
```

and method:

```
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
SomeObject *y = [[theTimer userInfo] objectForKey:@"y"];
SomeObject *z = [[theTimer userInfo] objectForKey:@"z"];
{etc...}
NSLog(@"Done");}
```

Now my question is how to call the method directly? I need to turn it on immediately not only after x time passed, so i wanted to call it. However this method returns crash([__NSCFDictionary userInfo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(timerAction:) withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:y, @"y", z, @"z", nil]];
```

Comment: timeAction method should have parameter of type NSDictionary because you are passing that from timer.

Comment: As far as i know it shouldn't have such parameter but NSTimer. Responces below seems to agree in this point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do this,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:y, @"y", z, @"z", nil] repeats:NO];
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:x target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:y, @"y", z, @"z", nil] repeats:YES];
```

Comment: @vive. I know it is not you. For down voting more reputation is needed than you have now. No problem about down voting,if there is a good reason i would love to correct myself.After all we are here learn and share.

Answer (score 4):

As Vignesh suggested, you could just call the NSTimer with a time interval of 0. However, this could cause problems in the future.

You would be better to have a function that does the processing,

`-(void)doProcessing:(NSDictionary *)theData {...`

And then have a timer method

```
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)timer {
[self doProcessing:[timer userInfo]];
}
```

So you can then call it through the timer as you currently have, or you can call it directly with `[self doProcessing:data]`

If you do it this way, then you will be much better placed if in the future you decide that after doing the processing you want to re-schedule the timer according to certain conditions but only if it was called through the timer as you can then do that in your timerAction method. You should try to get the functionality into as fine grained methods as possible, so don't mix the timer related bits with the processing bits.

Comment: Thats also a good idea, but the code is given later to client and i want to keep it as simple as possible for them not to get lost ;) Thanks for suggestions, will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: From the perspective of another developer coming to look at your code, this is the simpler version as you are separating your concerns and it is clear where the responsibility for handling the processing is and where the responsibility for handling the timer related function is. Obviously it's up to you as it's your code, but I would want to provide my client with the best code I could rather than trying to "simplify" it for them as that would just look as though I didn't know better.

Comment: Using a timer when you actually wanted to call the method directly is not as simple as possible. In my opinion it is ambiguous code that needs further explanation. Using a timer with interval 0 does something completely different than calling the timer method directly. The timer fires after the current runloop, the direct call happens immediately.

Comment: +1 for proper solution! It is also the one easiest to understand. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (before trying to call the selector) :

```
NSTimer* t = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
[[t userInfo] setObject:y forKey:@"y"];
[[t userInfo] setObject:x forKey:@"x"];
```

Then call it, either by :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(timerAction:) withObject:t];
```

or :

```
[self timerAction:t];
```

Comment: won't work. userInfo is nil unless you pass an object when you create the timer with one of the special init calls. Unfortunately userInfo is readonly too, so you can't add a dictionary to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like Vive wanted to originally, but do some introspection in the timerAction method to see what class the argument is:

```
-(void)timerAction:(id) param {
NSDictionary *dict = [param isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]? param : [(NSTimer *)param userInfo];
id y = [dict objectForKey:@"y"];
id z = [dict objectForKey:@"z"];
NSLog(@"%@  %@",y,z);
```

}